# Question about iterator

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations, evaluation

I am new to Mathematica. I just want to evaluate a 2x2 Jacobian and then evaluate it on different values of the two variables x and y.

The values I want to use to evaluate the Jacobian are the result of NDSolve.

Code:

```
f[x_, y_] := 2 - 10 x^2;
g[x_, y_] := 10 y - 2 y^2;

sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == f[x[t], y[t]], y'[t] == g[x[t], y[t]], x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}];

JacobianMatrix[f_List?VectorQ, x_List] := 
  Outer[D, f, x] /; Equal @@ (Dimensions /@ {f, x});

lx = Flatten[Map[x, Range[0, 10, 0.1]] /. sol];
ly = Flatten[Map[y, Range[0, 10, 0.1]] /. sol];
```

Now I want to evaluate the

```
JacobianMatrix[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, y}]
```

on the values of lx and ly (no combinations), just take one value of each one and produce a Jacobian.

I've tried Map and Table and combinations with no result.

Any help is welcomed. Thanks!

Comment: also tried Evaluate and @@

Comment: I am trying with few values to try to make it work, for example JacobianMatrix[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, y}] /@ {{0, 1}} with no luck.

Comment: this is working but not giving the intended result:

JC[{xx_, yy_}] := JacobianMatrix[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, y}] /. {x -> xx, y -> yy}

JC /@ {{lx, ly}}

Because I need a list of Jacobian matrices as result.

Comment: this is not working:

JC[xx_, yy_] := JacobianMatrix[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, y}] /. {x -> xx, y -> yy}
Map[JC, {{lx,ly}}]

Comment: this is neither working...

JC[xx_, yy_] := JacobianMatrix[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, y}] /. {x -> xx, y -> yy}

Table[JC[x, y], {x, {1, 2, 3, 4}}, {y, {5, 6, 7, 8}}]

Comment: Why didn't you fix the error by editing the question?

Comment: Done. I've edited the question. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method 1:

```
ans = Transpose[
   Map[Thread,
    D[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {{x, y}}] /. {x -> lx, y -> ly},
    2],
   {2, 1, 3}];
MatrixForm /@ ans
```

Method 2:

```
ans = MapThread[
   Function[{x, y}, Evaluate@D[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {{x, y}}]],
   {lx, ly}];
```

---

*Answer to original question*

Your Jacobian matrix is constant.  There's no need to evaluate it at many different points.

```
JacobianMatrix[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, y}]
(*  {{-10, 0}, {0, 8}}  *)
```

Note a common way to compute the Jacobian matrix is (search for Jacobian the docs for [`D`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D.html)):

```
D[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {{x, y}}]
```

Comment: sorry, I've simplified the original problem to keep it simple and it was too much of a simplification... now I've set y^2 and x^2 the Jacobian is not constant. thanks.

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly. I've tried for hours with no luck... Mathematica learning curve is a bit steep...

Comment: @CharlesM You're welcome. :)

Comment: I think what I've found difficult was to distinguish between the different types of objects that mathematica can handle. List, List of lists, Matrix, etc